# Path space of $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory, geodesic

Suppose that $p,q$ are two non conjugate points on $S^n$ ($p \ne q,-p$). Then there are infinite geodesics $\gamma_0, \gamma_1, \cdots$ from $p$ to $q$. Let $\gamma_0$ denote the short great circle arc from $p$ to $q$; let $\gamma_1$ denote the long great circle arc $p(-q)(-p)q$ and so on. The subscript $k$ denotes the number of times that $p$ or $-p$ occurs in the interior of $\gamma_k$. Why the index $\lambda(\gamma_k)= k(n-1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ be a geodesic on a Riemannian manifold $M$. The index $\gamma$ is, by definition (and depending on your definition!), the number of points on $\gamma$ conjugate to $\gamma(0)$ counted with multiplicity. If we're on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$, then it's a computation that the only points conjugate to $p\in \mathbb{S}^n$ are $p$ and $-p$ (the point of $\mathbb{S}^n$ antipodal to $p$). Moreover, the multiplicity of the conjugate point $-p$ is $n-1$ if $n$ is the dimension of $\mathbb{S}^n$. In English (but advanced English!), there are $n-1$ linearly independent Jacobi fields along a geodesic defining a great circle arc from $p$ to $-p$ whose values at the endpoints are zero.

If you understand this, then all you need to do is to figure out how many times $p$ and $-p$ occur on the geodesic $\gamma_k$ (not including the first time corresponding to $\gamma_k(0)$ if $\gamma_k$ is viewed a function from $[0,1]$ to $M$). And this number is:

$0$ for $\gamma_0$ (because the **short** great circle arc from $p$ to $q$ doesn't contain $-p$ (because it's **short**!))

$n-1$ for $\gamma_1$ (because $-p$ occurs once on the geodesic $\gamma_1$ and with multiplicity $n-1$ as explained above)

$\cdots$

$k(n-1)$ for $\gamma_k$ (because the number of times $p$ or $-p$ occurs on $\gamma_k$, not including the first time $p$ occurs at the initial point, is exactly $k$; I encourage you to visualise this for at least $k=2$)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I dont't know why the only points conjugate to $p$ are $p$ and $-p$ and why the multiplicity of the conjugate point $-p$ is $n-1$... Ours definitions are the same! Surely $p$ is conjugate, but why $-p$ is conjugate and there aren't other points?

Comment: @ArthurStuart Could you please have a look at: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/635W12/Notes/Lec%2025.pdf ? It's a three page PDF so it's short and the third page discusses conjugate points on Riemannian manifolds with constant sectional curvature. Skim through pages 1 and 2 to see if you're comfortable with that. If you are, then read page 3 noting that the sectional curvature of $\mathbb{S}^n$ is constant and equal to $1$. (In the notation of page 3 of the document, $k=1$.)

Comment: @ArthurStuart If you understand page 3 of this PDF, then it should be clear that (in the notation of page 3 of this PDF), $J_i=\sin(t)e_i$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ are linearly independent Jacobi fields such that $J_i(0)=0=J_i(\pi)$. Since $\gamma(\pi)=-\gamma(0)$ (again using the notation of page 3), it follows that the the antipode of the initial point of $\gamma$ is conjugate to the initial point of $\gamma$ with multiplicity $n-1$.    Since $\gamma '$ and $J_i$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ constitute a basis for the real vector space of all Jacobi fields along $\gamma$ with initial value zero ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... and their zeros only occur at $0$ and $\pi$, $-p$ is the only point conjugate to $p$, i.e., there can't be any other conjugate points. Does that answer your question? (In case I don't reply immediately, it will be because I'm away from stack exchange for the next few hours; but I think the PDF I cited is quite clear.) Just let me know if you have any further questions and I can answer them when I'm next active on stack exchange.

Comment: I don't know why the multiplicity is $n-1$. The other things are very clear.

Comment: I don't know why the multiplicity is $n−1$. The other things are very clear

Comment: @ArthurStuart Thanks for accepting my answer! Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic with initial point $p$ and endpoint $-p$. To say that the multiplicity of the conjugate point $-p$ to $p$ is $n-1$ is to say that there are $n-1$ linearly independent Jacobi fields along $\gamma$ which vanish at both $p$ and $-p$. I have noted in the comments above that the Jacobi fields defined by the rules $J_i(t)=\sin(t)e_i(t)$ for $t\in [0,\pi]$ and $i=2,\dots,n$ are linearly independent. To clarify, $e_i(t)$ are parallel orthonormal vector fields along $\gamma$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ with $e_1(t)=\gamma'(t)$ ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... You can verify directly that $J_i$ satisfies the Jacobi equation for $i=2,\dots,n$ because the $e_i$'s are parallel (and thus you just need to differentiate $\sin(t)$ in order to compute covariant derivatives of $J_i$ along $\gamma$). Finally, once you've done this it's clear by the definition that the multiplicity of the conjugate point $-p$ to $p$ is $n-1$ ($J_2,\dots,J_n$ furnish $n-1$ linearly independent Jacobi fields along $\gamma$ vanishing at the endpoints). Does that answer your question? If not, please let me know ...

Comment: Now algebrically the solution is very clear. But how can I imagine geometrically Jaboci fields on $S^2$, for example? (If our points are north and south pole)...

Comment: @ArthurStuart Let us consider a great circle arc on $\mathbb{S}^2$ from the north pole to the south pole. Let this be defined by a geodesic $\gamma$. Now, there are two linearly independent Jacobi fields along $\gamma$. Firstly, it's always the case that $\gamma'$ is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$; it's the tangent vector field to $\gamma$. The other linearly independent Jacobi field can be thought of as follows: if $\gamma$ is oriented "downward" from the north pole to the south pole, then the other Jacobi field points horizontally and it's magnitude is given by the $\sin$ function ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... So, initially its  magnitude is zero, as you move downward its magnitude increases until you hit time $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (which corresponds to the point on the midpoint of the great circle arc from the north pole to the south pole) after which it decreases back to zero when you hit time $\pi$ (which corresponds to the south pole). Notice that this **magnitude** resembles the $\sin$ function. However, the **direction** is always the same and points horizontally. (Of course, there are two horizontal directions, left and right, but it doesn't matter which you choose as long as ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... you fix one!)

Comment: I have a last question. Using the Fundamental theorem of Morse Theory we discover that $\Omega(S^n)$ is homotopically equivalent to a CW complex with one cell each in dimentions $o,n-1,2(n-1), \cdots$ and so on. But how can I attack these cells? For example $\Omega(S^2) \simeq e^0 \cup e^1 \cup^2 \cup \cdots $. But I don't think that $\Omega(S^2)$ is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$...

Comment: @ArthurStuart Of course, $\Omega(S^2)$ isn't homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$. In fact, they don't even have isomorphic homotopy groups. The reason is that the universal cover of $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ is the contractible infinite dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^{\infty}$. It's a (easy to prove) theorem that for $n\geq 2$, $\pi_n$ of the universal cover of a space agrees with $\pi_n$ of the space. Therefore, $\pi_n(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty})=0$ for $n\geq 2$. Finally, $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty})=\mathbb{Z}/2$ because the universal cover has fiber of cardinality $2$.

Comment: @ArthurStuart Could you please elaborate on your question? In general it's a hard problem to explicitly compute the attaching maps of cells in a CW complex. The homotopy type of $\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is equally as complicated as the homotopy type of $\mathbb{S}^2$ because $\pi_n(\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2))\cong \pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ (this is easy to prove using either the pathspace fibration or the loopspace/suspension adjunction).

Comment: @ArthurStuart If you're interested in computing homology, then the situation is nice for $n>2$. In this case, $\Omega(\mathbb{S}^n)$ has exactly one cell in each nonnegative integer multiple of $n-1>1$. Therefore, in cellular homology, the differentials are all zero and $H_i(\Omega(\mathbb{S}^n))=\mathbb{Z}$ if $i$ is a nonnegative integer multiple of $n-1$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: @ArthurStuart The situation is more subtle in the case $n=2$. In the cellular complex for $\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2)$, there is a $\mathbb{Z}$ in each degree but the differentials are (a priori) unknown. So, an alternative approach is needed.

Comment: @ArthurStuart The approach that immediately comes to mind is the Serre spectral sequence applied to the pathspace fibration of $\mathbb{S}^2$. All the differentials on the $E_2$ page must be isomorphisms (except the ones that originate from the zero group and enter a nonzero group) because the $E_2$ page equals the $E_{\infty}$ page (and the $E_{\infty}$ page just has a $\mathbb{Z}$ in the $(0,0)$ lattice point because the pathspace of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is contractible) ...

Comment: @ArthurStuart ... Since the differentials on the $E_2$ page go two units to the left and one unit up, it follows that the homology groups of $\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2)$ are all isomorphic and and the common isomorphism class (given by, e.g., the zeroth homology group!) is $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $H_i(\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2))=\mathbb{Z}$ for all nonnegative integers $i$. The same result holds for cohomology by the universal coefficient theorem. However, the homotopy groups of $\Omega(\mathbb{S}^2)$ are unknown because they're unknown for $\mathbb{S}^2$!

Comment: @ArthurStuart I've reproduced the comments above in an answer to your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438054/fundamental-theorem-fo-morse-theory-for-omegasn/438085#438085 . We can continue the discussion in the comment thread to my answer there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but on $S^2$ we find two Jacobi fields, and $dim(S^2)=2$, we said that there are $n-1$ Jacobi fields...

Comment: @ArthurStuart Hi Arthur, I don't think we said that. We said that there were $n-1$ linearly independent Jacobi fields *vanishing at both endpoints* along a geodesic between antipodal points on $\mathbb{S}^n$. Of course, the real vector space of Jacobi fields along a geodesic between conjugate points on $\mathbb{S}^n$ has dimension $n$. However, the tangent field to the geodesic is obviously Jacobi but doesn't vanish at either endpoint; we only care about  Jacobi fields vanishing at both endpoints when computing multiplicities of conjugate points so we ignore the tangent field.

Comment: I'm very sorry! It was a stupid question... I didn't think that $\gamma^{'}$ doesn't null in the second endpoint.

Comment: @ArthurStuart No problem. Let me add, though, that $\gamma'$ doesn't null the first endpoint either ...